# Why use .iter() in a for loop | Rust

Tags: rust

In these two examples is there any benefit in using .iter() in a for loop?

```rust
let chars = ['g', 'd', 'k', 'k', 'n'];

for i in chars {
    println!("{}", i);
}
```

```rust
let chars = ['g', 'd', 'k', 'k', 'n'];

for i in chars.iter() {
    println!("{}", i);
}
```

Comment: Which language edition are you using?

Comment: The first version, without the explicit call to `.iter()`, implicitly calls `.into_iter()` from the `IntoIterator` trait. One consequence of this is that the loop will *take ownership* of `chars` instead of borrowing it; a second consequence is that `i` will be the owned `char` from the array instead of a reference to it.

Comment: The language edition is important here because behaviour regarding array iteration changed between edition 2018 and 2021 (see https://doc.rust-lang.org/edition-guide/rust-2021/IntoIterator-for-arrays.html).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`for i in array` is interpreted by the compiler as `for i in array.into_iter()`.

This means that you are iterating over elements of type `char`, and the array is copied (as an array is `Copy` if its elements are also `Copy`).

On the other hand, `for i in array.iter()` references the array instead iterates over elements of type `&char`, avoiding a copy.

Comment: You can also do `for i in &array` in 2021 and it would be interpreted as `for i in (&array).into_iter()`, which is equivalent to `for i in array.iter()` .

Comment: Wrong. The edition doesn't matter. It only matters for explicit `.iter()`. If you'd be using an old version it would matter, but it will just not compile.

Comment: Another thing to note is that because the array is `Copy`, this will not move it.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman Amended the answer to take into account the `Copy` behaviour. I'm still not convinced that edition does not matter, given that if in edition 2021, the implicit `for in array` form calls into_iterator, and performs a copy, it's certainly different behaviour than just referencing the array.

Comment: @SirDarius That is the point, that in edition <= 2018 you _also_ copy the array and not reference it.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman And this is the hacky part I reckon? I found the reference to this behaviour in the documentation. In 2018, if we use the short syntax, it translates to `array.into_iter()`, while explicitely writing `array.into_iter()` translates to `(&array).into_iter()`. Unfortunately, I can't delete my answer unless it is unaccepted. I'll amend instead.

Comment: The difference between editions is what happens when you use _explicit_ `.into_iter()`. This is pretty hacky, yes. The problem was the existing code relied on `array.into_iter()` to be the same as `array.iter()`, so this behavior was left unchanged. But existing code did not rely on for loop over `array` directly to be the same as `.iter()`, since it didn't compile (because the desugaring is not `array.into_iter()` but `IntoItrator::into_iter(array)`, and that does not account for auto deref).